# JSON with outer brackets in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

when i got a JSON file called "test.json" which looks like this:

```
[{
"name":"abc",
"parent":"null",
"children":[],
}
]
```

That means with the outer brackets `[]` wrapping the whole data, it is not possible to use it in d3.js with the hierarchy function:

```
 d3.json("test.json", function(a) {

    var hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(a),
        links = hierarchy.links()
        nodes = hierarchy.descendants();
```

Now, when i leave the brackets away, which means that "test.json" looks like this, it is possible to use the file:

```
{
"name":"abc",
"parent":"null",
"children":[],
}
```

Now, my question is: Is this a specific problem of d3.js in general, maybe with the combination of the `hierarchy` function or it is always not working, when wrap the whole file with brackets []?

Comment: [RTFM](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy) ~ *"Constructs a root node from the specified hierarchical data. The specified data must be an **object** representing the root node.*". You are passing an array, not an object. Try `d3.hierarchy(a.pop())`

Comment: An array can contain multiple elements. You need to decide what to do if your array contains more than one object.

Comment: @phil: `d3.hierarchy(a.pop())` really solved the problem. even worked when i got multiple elements.

Comment: `pop` just returns the **last** element in the array. Like @Barmar said, you need to decide what to do in the case of multiple elements

Comment: @Phil: I know that only the last element of the array gets returned, but I can tell you that I tried it with a JSON file with multiple nodes and it still worked fine. All nodes are shown up on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

The outer brackets signify an array. To get the object / map inside them, index it out:

```
a[0]
```

So if `a` is:

```
[   {
        "name": "abc",
        "parent": "null",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Then `a[0]` is just

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": []
}
```